# Ошибки Сборки Microsoft Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

Каковым бы код у меня ни был, в любом случае у меня после нескольких раз отладки в Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 пишет, что возникли некие "ошибки сборки", они всегда одни и те же:

> не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp7.exe" в  "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp7.exe". Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp7.exe", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.    ConsoleApp7
>
> не удалось скопировать "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp7.exe" в "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp7.exe". Превышено допустимое число повторных попыток (10). Произошел сбой. "System (4)" блокирует этот файл ConsoleApp7

Создаю новый проект, пишу в нем простенький код - работает, завершаю отладку, добавляю что-нибудь в него новое, запускаю снова отладку, выходит вот это вот. Как мне это исправить?
Я смотрел в диспетчере задач, так там "ConsoleApp7.exe" нигде не используется, а пишет что используется. Что за систем 4? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот сейчас, после того, как написал этот вопрос, запустил отладку того кода, у которого были "ошибки сборки". Все работало. 
И так часто бывает, что надо ждать 5 или 10 минут. Или перезапускать Visual Studio.

Comment: Кто-то использует файл. Если он не запущен (посмотрите в диспетчере), то какой нибудь Unlocker вам в помощь.

Comment: Используйте утилиту handle Марка Руссиновича. Она показывает PID процесса, который держит файл. Кроме того, я замечал, что она как бы помогает ускорить отпускание файла. Т.е. файл кто-то держит, но как только запустишь handle и получишь ответ "никто не держит файл" - то да, действительно, уже никто не держит. Кеши может какие сбрасываются при этом... не знаю. Но утилита маст хэв. А System... ну это ни о чём, там может всё что угодно висеть на system - от самой студии до антивирусов.

Comment: А вообще ошибка больше всего похожа на то, что сама студия и держит файл, как будто вы не закрыли окно дебага. Если закрыть проект и открыть снова (не закрывая студию или с закрытием), то ошибка та же?

Comment: Это глюк самой студии. Мне регулярно, но не постоянно, пишет о невозможности записать файл манифеста, когда запускаешь проект в режиме отладки. А если отдельно, сначала собрать, а потом запустить - все ок. Что-то где-то перемудрили с многпоточностью и разделением ресурсов во время билда, видимо.